# How to retrieve a single record using a foreign key column in LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I have List "StudentList" (have more than one records)
I have another list "CourseList" (contain more than one records)
StudentList (1) to (*) CourseList [Relationship]

I want to retrieve a record with courseID (column from CourseList) = 1000;

What I have Tried but unable to execute.

```
        var viewmodel = StudentList.Select(x => x.CourseList.Where(y => y.courseID == "1000"));
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume, your intention is to get single course having id value 1000 but you are actually returning list of courses to viewmodel. Can you try following line instead and see the end result?  var viewmodel = StudentList.SelectMany(x => x.CourseList.Where(y => y.courseID == "1000")).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: thank you, this one works like a charm! may i ask why select many is used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer you were looking for,

```
var viewmodel = StudentList.SelectMany(x => x.CourseList.Where(y => y.courseID == "1000")).FirstOrDefault();
```

Since you showed interest on how it's working and what selectMany does, I tied explaining a bit further though I have already answered your question in comments section,

1. First thing to notice, x.CourseList.Where(y => y.courseID == "1000") section will
   return list of courses whose id is 1000. Even if there is only one course, it will be
   list.
2. If we are getting list of courses whose id is 1000 for each individual student, we will
   end up getting List of List of courses(while using select).
3. So, here selectMany flattens the 'List of List of courses'  to 'List of courses' by
   merging all inner courses.
4. At last, FirstOrDefault() will make sure to return the single course object whose id is
   100 and which is the required result for you.

Note: though I have used the term List, you may be dealing with IEnumerable

Hope you and anybody else landing here find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this method

```
var result = students.Where(x=>isExistCourse(x));
public static bool isExistCourse(Student student)
    {
        foreach(var item in student.Courses)
        {
            if(item.Id==1000)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

if you only want to get one record, you can replace `where` to `FirstOrDefault`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am looking for a one line LINQ query